Get class reference in static method?
Is there a way within the context of a static method to access the class? I'm setting up a mock for a singleton class and I want to know if there's a generic way to configure the static Instance method so that it can use the current class constructor (but only really applies for unit tests, not production code). I'm using Jest for testing.
class Service {
  private static _instance: Service | undefined;
  public static get Instance() {
    if (this._instance === undefined) {
      this._instance = new Service(); // update this to use the derived class constructor?
    }
    return this._instance;
  }
  ...
}


why don't you separate the singleton-ness from the class and put it into a separate function that you can mock?

Your code already demonstrates how to access the current class object: this . You can use that with new as well (instead of Service).

@Bergi if I try this.new() I get a typescript error saying there's no such method

@DanielA.White I'm not unit testing the class in isolation - its a service that is used and required for testing my various other react components. I want to mock it so that it isn't trying to actually communicate with the back-end during unit testing.

@RyanPierceWilliams It's new this(), not this.new(). TypeScript might still give you some trouble about return types, you can declare a generic this parameter for that - see the duplicates

so mock the whole module/class

@DanielA.White it's complicated enough that I'd prefer to just mock specific functions + add test specific wrappers rather than mock it all from scratch, which could be a pain to maintain
